# Webpack loader for Javascript's new syntax

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new with Webpack. I had no problem at all while starting to compile until now. But now I have the following error:

> ERROR in ./js/logger.js 2:42 Module parse failed: Unexpected token
> (2:42) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,
> currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

This is the code:

```
class Logger {
    static __staticConstructorDummyResult = (function () {
        Logger.__loggableClasses = [];
    })()
}

export { Logger };
```

It is not the first time I have been forced to change my JS code so that Webpack does not complain. But I do not believe this is the usual way to handle with it when you have the chance to use some sort of those "loaders".

So it seems Webpack cannot understand this JS syntax (am I correct?), and it suggests to install some loader so it can. The problem is that I am not able to find any for this. And I wonder if this is a normal thing, since this syntax has been there [for a few time](https://caniuse.com/?search=javascript%20static).

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot'),
    entry: {
        logger: './js/logger.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/bundles/js'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Does anyone know how I can deal with these problems?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an `an appropriate loader to handle this file type`. When you do not know how to do that - post the code in question in a minimal reproducible way.

Comment: Hi @madflow. I though I did. It is the "Logger" class, whose code has only that piece of code.

Comment: You are posting a Webpack question without any Webpack configuration. So you do not configure Webpack in any way?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I did not understand you. As I said I am really new with Webpack, so you are right the config is important for the question. Let me edit it. Thanks.

Comment: @madflow I have just added the info. Please let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) - public static fields are currently an experimental feature (Stage-3).

> Support in browsers is limited, but the feature can be used through a build step with systems like Babel. See the compat information below.

The reference to [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) already yields how to solve the Webpack compile problem.

You will have to add Babel, Babel-Loader for Webpack and a Babel Plugin for this experimental feature to your development stack:

`npm install --save-dev babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

or with Yarn:

`yarn add -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

and amend the `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot'),
  entry: {
    logger: './js/logger.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot/bundles/js'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Amazing @madflow, now it transpiles with no problem. It even compiles other code I was having trouble with. So that was the needed plugin. Annotated. Thanks for your help!